# Django models: how to get a two tables left join including nulls on left

Tags: django-models

First post here and Django newbie, so please, be indulgent.

I've the base model User and another model with a User foreignkey:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

class UserDailyActivity(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    day = models.DateField()
    last_operation_time = models.TimeField()
    ...
```

I'm trying to reproduce in Django a simple sql query that list all User model records and some of the related UserDailyActivity columns, that may exist or not. In plain SQL:

```
SELECT 
    User.id,
    User.username,
    Daily.id as daily_id
FROM 
    User
LEFT JOIN 
    UserDailyActivity as Daily on (user.id = Daily.user_id)
WHERE 
    Daily.day = TODAY()
```

As expected, this is the query result, that includes the joined column:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | user_name  | daily_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | One        | NULL     |
|  4 | Two        | 10       |
|  5 | Three      | NULL     |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I've read different post here about use annotation, prefetch, filtered relation etc, but I've to admit that I failed miserably.

Can someone point me on the right way to get this working ?

Comment: Please *don't* think in term of queries, but in terms of data and models. Exactly *what* do you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve the related data from both models at same time, as the SQL query -it's just an example- explains. I know that I can obtain a QuerySet for the main model and then make another query to get the related data while looping on the results, but this is really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should not think in terms of *queries*, but in terms of models and data, so instead of designing a query and then trying to mimic this in the ORM, you should think *what* you need, and how you do this with the *Object Relational Mapper (ORM)*. This makes querying easier, but often the ORM will also optimize queries if specified effectively.

You can make a combination of filtering and annotating with:

```
from datetime import date

from django.db.models import F, Q

User.objects.filter(
    Q(userdailyactivity=None) | Q(userdailyactivity__day=date.today())
).annotate(daily_id=F('userdailyactivity'))
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).